# How to open a specific URL (a YouTube video) on a button click in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, url, uwp, uri

**EDIT:**
I was just checking if the entire Tag was blank, instead of the URL in the tag, so it resulted in being always blank and always throwing exceptions.

**I want to be able to open a specific URL on a button click, like a YouTube video, google search etc. in the user's default browser**

When using `await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));` the URLs are invalid and this method only opens 'normal' websites, like https://microsoft.com.

**Is there any way to open a specific URL on a button click?**

The code:

```
private async void imageTapEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((String)(((Image)sender).Tag)) != "")
                await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(((ImageTag)(((Image)sender).Tag)).url));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("The chosen URL is invalid", "Invalid URL");
            await msg.ShowAsync();
    }
```

The tag is the URL saved as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to open a specific URL in a UWP app?

Sure, UWP has [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-19041) control that use to render html page, you could give it uri source, then the WebView will render the website in the app. For more detail please refer Web view [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view).

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
```

**Update**

You could also launch the default browser to load the uri like the following

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string uriToLaunch = @"https://www.test.com";
    var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

    // Set the option to show a warning
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;

    // Launch the URI with a warning prompt
    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);

    if (success)
    {
        // URI launched
    }
    else
    {
        // URI launch failed
    }

}
```

Comment: But like I said, I wanted to open the URL in a default browser on a button click event. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you could launch uri with browser  by calling   `LaunchUriAsync` method.

Comment: But it can only open with the uri like using the browser to access uri.

Comment: And I've got a problem here, because when trying to launch a YouTube video, an exception is thrown. It only opens just websites, like microsoft.com, instead of an entire YouTube  video, like I said in the question. Is there any solution for that or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Please share your code in the case description.

Comment: I added the current code in the edited question.

Comment: Please check your uri is correct http uri ?

Comment: The user writes the URL in a textbox in a dialog. I added a YouTube video URL in the tag and it throws the exception, which is later caught. The URL is working properly, as I checked. The LaunchUriAsync() method just doesn't work with these URLs, URLs like https://bing.com work properly.

Comment: So, it does not contain *http* prefix?

Comment: The written URL contains it. When I write the url with the https prefix it opens only websites, not youtube videos etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226665/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-techrex-studios).